# Using assembly to create a fallback function with a return value?

Tags: evm, assembly, returndata

Is it possible to use Solidity assembly to create a fallback function that makes a `DELEGATECALL` to another contract, and then uses assembly to correctly store the return value of the `DELEGATECALL` in the appropriate registers, so that the fallback function effectively returns this value?

This is useful so that I can make a contract that behaves exactly like another contract, while maintaining the clones interoperability with solidity features.

-- EDIT --

Ok I've done some more research, and it seems like it should be possible to use assembly to push to the `returndata` of the EVM stack, but I can't find any particularly good documentation for the Ethereum VM that has the info I need. Where is the `returndata` in memory? What is the best way to write to it? Etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the fallback function.

https://github.com/rob-Hitchens/TrustlessUpgrades/blob/master/contracts/Proxy.sol

```
    function () external payable {
        address implementationAddress = userImplementation(msg.sender);
        //solium-disable-next-line security/no-inline-assembly
        assembly {
            let ptr := mload(0x40)
            calldatacopy(ptr, 0, calldatasize)
            let result := delegatecall(gas, implementationAddress, ptr, calldatasize, 0, 0)
            let size := returndatasize
            returndatacopy(ptr, 0, size)

            switch result
            case 0 { revert(ptr, size) }
            default { return(ptr, size) }
        }
    }
```

Disclaimer:

This code is inspired by others who were, no doubt, inspired by others. No testing of any kind and no warranty of any kind.

It's a proxy pattern for upgradeable contracts. It:

- Uses a fallback as a catch-all for implementation contract functions - gets them all.
- Uses delgatecall to forward the calldata to an implementation contract
- Copies the response to returndata
- Reverts if the implementation wanted to revert (returned fail). That replicates the called function's intended behaviour.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This certainly looks like what I need. Going to test and then accept this answer.